# How do I cancel a subscription for StreamBuilder in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I m currently facing a problem which is that my entire `HomeScreen` page is dependant on the `StreamBuilder` and the data that it is receiving from the firestore.

Everything is working well, but when I click sign out, I got this error :

> The caller does not have permission to execute the specified
> operation.

This is my firestore security rules :

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {

match /databases/{database}/documents {

 match /{document=**} {

  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;

  }

 }

}
```

I did some research and found that the reason was probably I did not Un-Subscribe to the stream when I press log out. Here is my stream Builder code :

```
late Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> bookSnapshot =
      firestore.collection('books').snapshots();
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
   stream: bookSnapshot,
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
   ...
   }
),
```

I m fairly new to this concept, and I really need help on how to un-subscribe to the stream.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: StreamBuilder are closed automatically when page is not in current context(if you push or pop to another page). To make stream Controllable try using StreamSubscription. It has cancel() resume() methods.

Comment: Did you implemented a solution? I would like to know how to do precisely this, without popping the page first.